# Aggregate Functions in Index with IBMDB2

Tags: sql, indexing, db2

Is there any way to pre aggregate results of aggregate functionts (f.i. count()) and store it in an index?

The background is: i want to speed up count() queries. So that:

Select count(users) from TE123
where region = 'A';

would be supported by an index like
Region Count(Users)
A      548
E      458

I know that MQTs would also help for this problem. However, in this case it is not possible to use MQT, as we use kind of an ORM and we don't want to define Entities on MQTs.

I just slightly remember - one DBA told me - that there is such a function planned for DB2 V10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTs will likely still help, even without rewriting the query.

> Materialized query tables can significantly improve the performance of
>   queries, especially complex queries. If the optimizer determines that
>   a query or part of a query could be resolved using an MQT, the query
>   might be rewritten to take advantage of the MQT.

[**SOURCE**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509melnyk/)

### For z/OS:

> Using a process called automatic query rewrite, DB2® recognizes when
>   it can transparently rewrite a submitted query to use the stored
>   results in a materialized query table. By querying the materialized
>   query table instead of computing the results from the underlying base
>   tables, DB2 can process some complicated queries much more
>   efficiently.

[**SOURCE**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.perf/src/tpc/db2z_mqtandaqr.htm)

### For Linux/Unix/Windows:

> Knowledge of MQTs is integrated into the SQL and XQuery compiler. In
>   the compiler, the query rewrite phase and the optimizer match queries
>   with MQTs and determine whether to substitute an MQT in a query that
>   accesses the base tables. If an MQT is used, the explain facility can
>   provide information about which MQT was selected. In this case, users
>   need access privileges against the base tables, not rerouted MQTs.

[**SOURCE**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005324.html)

Comment: just to double-check: You say that I can create a MQT on Table TE123 and can still leave the plans bind to read TE123 (possibly with rebind). So the select would remain as Select count(*) / * from TE123 and it automatically determines that the MQT can be used to increase performance?

Comment: Yes.  I've added some relevant quotes from the IBM documentation, for both the Mainframe (z/OS), and distributed (LUW) platforms.  IBM calls the feature "*Automatic Query Rewrite*"

Comment: Great! So this should also work with Static SQL where the access path is predefined by the DBAs, right?

Comment: With static SQL, you will have to re-bind your packages after the MQT is created (and the proper statistics are run). But yes, all SQL access should be able to use MQTs if they are appropriate.